# How to see that polynomial is fixed by finitely many values.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials

Let's say we have a polynomial $p(z)=\sum_{i=0}^n c_iz^i$. If we have $n+1$ known values $(z_i,w_i)$. We find 
\begin{align*}
    \sum_{i=0}^n c_iz_0^i&=w_0\\
    &\vdots\\
    \sum_{i=0}^n c_iz_n^i&=w_n
\end{align*}

Which comes down to row-reducing 
\begin{equation}
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc|c}
1c_1&z_0c_2&\ldots&z_0^n c_{n+1}&w_0\\
1c_1&z_1c_2&\ldots&z_1^nc_{n+1}&w_1\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\
1c_1&z_nc_2&\ldots&z^n_nc_{n+1}&w_n
\end{array}
\right)\label{matrix}
\end{equation}
For $i\neq j$ it holds that $z_i\neq z_j$. why do the rows have to be linearly independent, aka there has to be a unique solution for all the $c_i$. Therefore $p$ being determined by $n+1$ values?

Without using the fundamental theorem of algebra!

Comment: The deerminant of this linear system is a *Vandermonde determinant*, which happens to be equal to the product of the $c_i-c_j$ for all $1\le i<j\le n$n hence is non-zero.

Comment: The main ingredient for doing this as a linear algebra problem is the Vandermonde matrix https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix

Comment: @Bernard  you mean the product of the $z_i-z_j$, I think...

Comment: but ci and cj might be the same, so I think you mean zi-zj, since theyre different

Comment: @ChrisCuster: Yes, I meant the product of the $z_i-z_j$. Just a slip because of the unusual name for coefficients (for my excuse, it was rather late here when I wrote this comment…)